# What is the semantic HTML tag to display for URLs that are not links?

Tags: html, url, tags, semantics

I have a search engine plugin that outputs results in a basic structure:

```
<a href="page url">
    <div class="searchResult">
        <h3>Page title</h3>
        <p>Page url</p>
        <p>Page <meta> description</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

The plugin is designed to integrate into an existing website so it has no default styling. However, websites are supposed to be usable even without CSS through the use of the correct, semantic HTML tags. Currently the displayed URL is indistinguishable from the description and would appear as a software glitch without additional styling.

Google uses the `<cite>` tag, however in HTML 5 `<cite>` should be used for the title of a work, not a URL so this isn't the answer.

Is there a HTML tag that is designed to show a URL other than `<a>`, a URL that is not clickable? What is the semantic approach for this?

Comment: What's wrong with using `<a>`?

Comment: @Anonymous My understanding is the "that are not links" part means that it's a URL, but it's not clickable to navigate to the page. There might not be a semantic tag specifically for that purpose

Comment: @Anonymous What Katana314 said - it's a link displayed that shouldn't be clickable. I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: Why can't you just use a `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the url to be a link but also display as a url.  To do this put the url in the a tag twice, like so:

This can then be style as desired by the destination page.

```html
<style>
a {
color: blue;
text-decoration: underline; }
</style>

<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a><br /><br />

Edited to add:<br /><br />

<a>http://www.google.com/</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I didn't clarify but I meant a tag that displayed a URL without it being clickable. Would an `<a>` tag without `href` attribute be a 'semantic' way of displaying a URL without actually creating a link though?

Comment: Apparently so.  I've edited my answer to include doing it like that.  And it does display the link in an a tag without it being clickable.

Comment: I was also able to style the a tag with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` attribute is required for default link styling.

Since adding css seems to be an issue I doubt you can use JS but if you can [here's a solution](http://jsfiddle.net/s4edy526/4/) that requires the css class `.do-not-open` to prevent links from opening.